# What is the best way to achieve the following result?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have the following data:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    metadata: {
      attributes: [
        {
          type: 'background',
          value: 'red',
        },
        {
          type: 'background',
          value: 'blue',
        },
        {
          type: 'size',
          value: 'small',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    metadata: {
      attributes: [
        {
          type: 'background',
          value: 'red',
        },
        {
          type: 'background',
          value: 'blue',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    metadata: {
      attributes: [
        {
          type: 'background',
          value: 'red',
        },
        {
          type: 'background',
          value: 'green',
        },
        {
          type: 'size',
          value: 'small',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

For each object in the attributes array I have to create a new object based on the type property. The type property will be a key in this new object and the value will be another property nested inside. The value of the nested property will be an array that contains all the corresponding ids. So, I have to achieve something like this as a final result:

```
const desiredResult = {
    background: {
      red: [1, 2, 3], //these are ids
      blue: [1, 2],
      green: [3],
    },
    size: {
      small: [1, 3],
    },
};
```

Comment: what goes wrong? what have you tried?

Comment: I am currently creating this new object with a nested loop (objects in the data array and then attributes array inside each data object). But I am looking for a better solution since these loops are inside a service that queries a database later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `for each` or `for ... of` in javascript. clean code for beginner like below:

```js
function process (data) {
    let result = {};
    for (let datum of data) {
        for (let attribute of datum.metadata.attributes) {
            result[attribute.type] = result[attribute.type] || {};
            result[attribute.type][attribute.value] = result[attribute.type][attribute.value] || [];
            result[attribute.type][attribute.value].push(datum.id);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
//
const desiredResult = process(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach much like the others here, but using immutable data, even for the accumulator:

```js
const extract = (xs) => xs .reduce ((a, {id, metadata: {attributes = []} = {}}) => 
  attributes .reduce ((a, {type: t, value: v}) => 
    ({...a, [t]: {... (a [t] || {}), [v]: [...((a [t] || {}) [v] || []), id]}}), 
  a), {})

const data = [{id: 1, metadata: {attributes: [{type: "background", value: "red"}, {type: "background", value: "blue"}, {type: "size", value: "small"}]}}, {id: 2, metadata: {attributes: [{type: "background", value: "red"}, {type: "background", value: "blue"}]}}, {id: 3, metadata: {attributes: [{type: "background", value: "red"}, {type: "background", value: "green"}, {type: "size", value: "small"}]}}]

console .log (extract (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This works for many sizes of data, but it can run into a [performance problem](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) if the data is really large.  If you do, then you might have to choose a mutable accumulator instead.  But I wouldn't worry about it unless this function shows itself to be a bottleneck in your application.